# uso de regex em um switch

Tags: javascript, regex, switch

Estou tentando usar expressões regulares para validar um switch, porém, me ocorre no console que "day.match" is not a function:

```
function dayOfWeek(day){
   var regex = /[1-7]/g;
   if(!day.match(regex)){
      day == 8;
   }
   switch(day){
      case 1: return "Segunda";
      break;
      case 2: return "Terça";
      break;
      case 3: return "Quarta";
      break;
      case 4: return "Quinta";
      break;
      case 5: return "Sexta";
      break;
      case 6: return "Sábado";
      break;
      case 7: return "Domingo";
      break;
      case 8: return "Dia inválido";
      break;
   }
}
```

O que há de errado, e como posso corrigir ?

Comment: Verifique o "day", a mensagem esta informando que o match não existe no "day", é possível que você esteja mandando algo de errado no "day".

Comment: justamente como é minha pergunta, como vou verificar se não sei o que isso pode significar ?

Comment: Coloque assim console.log(day), e veja no console o que esta chegando em "day"

Comment: sua var `day` é uma instancia do objeto `Date`?

Comment: nao é @GuilhermeLautert , apenas um dia inserido pelo usuário

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você pode estar tentando usar `match` em um *number*, o correto seria:

```
var regex = /[1-7]/;
if( !regex.test(day) ){
    day = 8;
}
```

**Exemplo**

```js
function dayOfWeek(day){
   var regex = /([1-7])/;
   if( !regex.test(day) ){
      day = 8;
   }

   switch(day){
      case 1: return "Segunda";
      break;
      case 2: return "Terça";
      break;
      case 3: return "Quarta";
      break;
      case 4: return "Quinta";
      break;
      case 5: return "Sexta";
      break;
      case 6: return "Sábado";
      break;
      case 7: return "Domingo";
      break;
      case 8: return "Dia inválido";
      break;
   }
}

console.log(dayOfWeek(5))
console.log(dayOfWeek(9))
```

---

Dessa forma a regex irá testar se o parâmetro é *true* ou *falso*. Mas o seu caso dispensa o uso de regex, poderia usar o default do `switch`:

```js
function dayOfWeek(day){

    switch(day){
      case 1: return "Segunda";
      break;
      case 2: return "Terça";
      break;
      case 3: return "Quarta";
      break;
      case 4: return "Quinta";
      break;
      case 5: return "Sexta";
      break;
      case 6: return "Sábado";
      break;
      case 7: return "Domingo";
      break;
      default: return "Dia inválido";
      break;
   }
}

console.log(dayOfWeek(5));
console.log(dayOfWeek(9));
```